# Latitude/longtitude conversion to image x/y coordinates (Miller Cylindrical projection)

Tags: latitude-longitude, map-projections

As already said in the title, I need some help with converting lat/long to x/y coords in Miller Cylindrical projection. I`m currently writing an app (in Java) which gets city list as an input and then gets lat/long for each city from Yahoo Placefinder. I used [these](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillerCylindricalProjection.html) formulas in my code. [Here is an example](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/6572/99432143.png) of what I get. (image is for the reference only, not the one I use). As you can see the X positions are only a few pixels (2-3) off, this can be a problem with my calculations of prime meridian shift (CENTRAL_MERIDIAN_OFFSET) in this map. But the main problem is incorrect Y coordinates.

Here is my code (updated - 34px compensation for equator offset):

```
public final double W = 6343;
public final double H = 4767 - 34;

protected Point toMillerXY(double lon, double lat)
{
    double x, y;

    lon = Utils.degToRad(lon);
    lat = Utils.degToRad(lat);

    x = lon - CENTRAL_MERIDIAN_OFFSET;
    y = 1.25 * Math.log( Math.tan( 0.25 * Math.PI + 0.4 * lat ) );

    x = ( W / 2 ) + ( W / (2 * Math.PI) ) * x;
    y = ( H / 2 ) - ( H / ( 2 * 2.303412543 ) ) * y;

    y += 34;

    return new Point(x, y);
}

Output:  
Fetching data with: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=Buenos+Aires,Argentina
Latitude: -34.608521, longitude: -58.373539
---
Fetching data with: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=Tokyo,Japan
Latitude: 35.670479, longitude: 139.740921
---
Fetching data with: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=Cape+Town,CAR
Latitude: -33.919060, longitude: 18.421961
---
Fetching data with: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=Rome,Italy
Latitude: 41.903110, longitude: 12.495760
---
Total cities: 4
Result for Buenos Aires: 1964.598428, 3046.740995
Result for Tokyo: 5455.265150, 1732.669551
Result for Cape Town: 3317.692474, 3032.814395
Result for Rome: 3213.276105, 1602.176163
```

Obviously, something is wrong with Y coord calculation. I`m not sure whether 5.6 should really be the right value but the vertical range of Millers projection was said to be -2.3..+2.3 in one of the references I read so I used it.

Comment: `Here is an example of what I get` Where is it?

Comment: Forgot to add the image, fixed that.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question - its audience is much more focussed on this kind of problem

Comment: Thanks for the info, I might as well post this there.

Comment: @Varnius  do you have an exact image you used? The one presented by you is incorrect as the equator do not pass through the center of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Millers projection was said to be -2.3..+2.3` it is an approximation. Based on the size of an image you might need more precise value, for example `2.303412543`

For latitude of Moscow as 55.7522222 it will give `y = 1.089472895` and, based on the height of the image I used,  `y' = 1499/2 - (1499/ (2 * 2.303412543)) * 1.089472895 = 395` pixels from the top, which is correct (I did not care about x).

Check it, I placed a red dot on the map.
http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/9892/mapue.jpg

So, probably your image does not have equator in the middle of it. It can be fixed mathematically by addition of the shift to the formula, but you have to find position of the equator.

Comment: I was using [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/World_map_%28Miller_cylindrical_projection%2C_blank%29.svg) SVG map. And really, it seems that equator there is a bit off and I didn`t notice that before. I`ll check that out and accept your answer if it is really the case.

Comment: @Varnius Equator on it is almost at the right place. Anyway, check the height of the image you are working with. Formula is correct and by the shift of the position at your example I would assume that the wrong height of the image was used in calculations.

Comment: I might have done some mistakes while marking the cities in previous example. Anyway, I just took a very big 6343x4767 version of that svg and updated my code to compensate 34px offset in this image. What I get now are good positions for southern hemisphere and bad ones for northern one. I marked results for some cities (also added output of the code above) for both hemispheres [in this image](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/2420/milleroriginal.png). I`m pretty sure that I missed something but just don`t know what. :~

Comment: @Varnius  can you provide some sample coordinates? I can take them from google, but I want to see what you are using.

Comment: I updated my output with Yahoo Placefinder http queries and fetched lat/long. Check the main post.

Comment: @Varnius I see what the problem is. SVG image is incorrect, try your code on this image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Miller_projection_SW.jpg   ps: `double H = 4767 - 34;` is also not a correct way.

Comment: Why is `- 34` thingy bad for compensating equator offset? I added 34 afterwards. And yeah, it seems that my map was wrong. Now I`ll have a hard time searching for another one SVG as precise as this one. Anyway, thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: @Varnius `thingy bad for compensating equator offset` its a simple math, when you divide it by 2 it means that your middle line of the image is shifted by 17 pixels down and then you move it up by 34. In total it will give a shift of 17 pixels, for example, for the position of the equator. Anyway, I tried to combined both maps in Photoshop.. even when I scale to the same size of Africa, for example.. the result you can see here http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/1839/69008841.jpg  I've added transparency to the vector one, shifted, scaled it. But there is still some difference.

Comment: @Varnius  so, in general, you can use SVG map, but, as you can see from the combined picture, it will give you larger error when you are further away from the equator. The major difference is that the SVG map does not reach 90 degrees latitude, meaning that you should not use `2.3` for it. Let me see how much it reaches. Ok, it is approximately `86.4953` degrees.

Comment: @Varnius Ok, look here http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/1873/52686459.jpg with 86.49 degrees of the map coverage it gives more or less better results. For that latitude you should use `2.11896` instead of `2.3`. As you can see Cape Town is still shifted, so the actual maximum of the latitude is even smaller (parallels are not equidistant on that map), play with the value of `2.11896` slightly increasing it.

Comment: Heh, I need good precision even when zoomed in quite a lot so I guess I`ll generate something with this [nice utility](http://indiemapper.com/app/) I found and skip playing with that incorrect svg. But thanks anyway!